# GeoServer deploy over LAN

Tags: geoserver, network

I have set up GeoServer on a mac mini running OSX Mavericks. I have my Mac hooked up to my LAN and would like to start developing geographic web applications.

I have a bunch of data sitting in my PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. I have a handful of map services set up in GeoServer. I even have a few nice styles put together to make everything look nice. I put together a little introductory web application the get the geography party started on my LAN but for the life of me, I can't seem to consume the geography remotely.

I access the service with a little bit of Javascript:

```
var map;

function mapinitialize() {
    bluemap = new L.TileLayer.WMS(GEOSERVERBASE +     "/geoserver/phillystreetmap/wms",
{
    layers: "phillystreetmap:Philly",
    format: 'image/png',
    attribution: ""
});

map = new L.Map('map',
    {
        center: new L.LatLng(37.45, -77.5),
        zoom: 12,
        layers: [bluemap],
        zoomControl: true
    });
}
```

and it looks great running locally on the server. However, when I try to access the site from another computer on my LAN, everything but the geography shows up. The error I get for the tiles is:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/phillystreetmap/wms?service=WMS&request=Get…x=-8619650.805662755,4500612.225431179,-8609866.86604225,4510396.165051683 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any idea why the data would show up when I run the application locally on the server but not when I access the site remotely?

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking the port 8080. No experience with Macs but that's the first place to look on a PC. Also it's looking for localhost, that should be substituted for your computer name or IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your JavaScript is running on the client machine. So when you do a GET to localhost:8080, that is to whatever service is running on *port 8080 on the client*. There almost certainly isn't one, and even if it is, that isn't what you want - you want the service running on port 8080 *on the server*.

So to address this problem, you need to make sure that your javascript is configured to point to the server.

In your example code, `GEOSERVERBASE` isn't shown, but it probably looks something like `http://localhost:8080`. Instead, you need to put in the real host name for your server (which might require updating DNS, or hard-coding an IP address, if you don't have DNS support or aren't allowed to configure it).

Further debugging (firewalls, network issues) can use a browser session - start with your web browser (firefox, chrome, etc) pointing to your server on port 8080 - `http://server_ip:8080/geoserver`